# .data function and/or jsonrequest method

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Here is my `.ajax` call :

```
(function($){

  var bindEvents = function(node){
    $('.btn-fax', node).bind('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {};
      var fax_number = {{ contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number }};
      $.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        data : data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (data.success) {
              console.log('place 1');
              if (data.redirect_to) {
                console.log('place 2');
                window.location.href = data.redirect_to;
              }
              else if (data.reload) {
                console.log('place 3');
                window.location.reload();
              }
          }
          else {
            console.log('place 4');
            alert('Error! See console for details :(');
            console.error(textStatus, data);
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(fax_number);
            console.log(fax_number === '');
            if (!fax_number) {
                alert('Please, attach the fax number to your profile');
                return;
            }
            console.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  };

  $.lw.on('init', function(args){
    bindEvents(args.node);
  });

})(typeof(django) == 'undefined' ? jQuery : django.jQuery);
```

and here is the portion of my django template which use the button :

```
<a href="{% url "contracts:fax" pk=object.contract.pk %}" class="btn pull-right {{ object.state|request_state_color }} darken-2 btn-fax" data-turbolinks="false">{%trans "Fax contract" %}</a>
```

My code is not being rendered by Django - It is in a separate JavaScript file, not in a Django template. Hence, I could not define a variable as `var fax_number = {{ contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number }};` Somme people told me that I could use a jQuery .data() function or I can build a server-side api that renders the fax number as part of a JSON object (use the django jsonrequest method). Could anyone have time to show me how I could do such thing with my code.

We told me that I can add a data-fax attribute to a DIV tag with `id "contact"` and then use `var fax = $("#contact").data("fax)`. The problem is I don't know how to use that with Django. I started using javascript very recently and that's why I need your help.

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** Please let me know if my question is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass some dynamic data from django to your javascript, you need to do so in your template.

There are 2 reasons for this:

1. Django is not responsible for serving static files (javascript) in production. It is not compiled on a per request basis -- that's what templates are for.
2. If you dynamically inserted new data into your JS, then user's browsers would not be able to cache it. This can affect the performance of your website if you force users to redownload static files every time they visit a page.

So as you said, your template would look like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* Remember to wrap these in quotes if they need to be strings.
      You may also need to use the |safe filter for some data types
      to ensure django doesn't escape them (e.g. JSON) */
      var fax_number = {{ contract.request.customer.convert_fax_number }};
    </script>

    <!-- Import your JS file AFTER defining your variables -->
    <script src="src.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to type 'text/javascript' or the name the `.js` file?

Comment: You can omit `type="text/javascript"` if you're importing a JS file. I believe it's only necessary if the user is using a browser older than IE8.